# Make image button in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, button, background, background-image

I am trying to make a button in jQuery Mobile that has svg as background image, and can't get it right. I don't want icon button, I want button that has image as background. Here is m< code

```
<div class="ui-block-a">
   <a data-role="button" class="red-button" href="login.html">LOGIN</a>
</div>


.red-button {
    background-image: url(../img/buttons/button-red.svg) !important;
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong here. Thanks.

Comment: Which version of jQuery Mobile are you using?

Comment: <script src="spec/lib/jquery.mobile-1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

Comment: Seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/jtgf2w1n/. What is not working for you?